# BST Supernodes Generation in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

How can I generate a binary search tree with supernodes in C/C++?

Answer (score 3):

1. Obtain a reference describing the data structure. http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/papers/super.pdf
2. Implement the data structure in C/C++.