# Binary Search Tree with Supernodes Algorithm

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, binary-search-tree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BST Supernodes Generation in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494837/bst-supernodes-generation-in-c-c)

Can someone help me implement the generation, addition and deletion of a binary search tree with supernodes? I really need an algorithm in C/C++.

Comment: what have you done so far? have you tried? this sounds like homework...

Comment: The algorithm is language agnostic. The implementation of the algorithm you want is to be in C or C++. +1 on sounds like homework.

Comment: As I never heard of this, based on a quick search - this seems to refer to something that's a cross between a BST and a multiway tree. Each node holds multiple keys, but has (at most) two children. Left children only hold keys less-than the lowest parent key, right children only hold keys greater-than the highest parent key. I could easily be wrong, though.

Comment: The best thing that you can do is to understand what the requirements are. As a good exercise, you can start by editing this question and adding what a *Binary Search Tree with Supernodes* is. Being able to express it will help you understand what it is, and that will aid in understanding the algorithms and later the implementation. Once you have the description of what you want, just ask on what you do not understand.

Comment: @David: Same IP (based on the user picture), so it is the same question by the same person. Downvote + vote to close for me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [BST Supernodes Generation in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494837/bst-supernodes-generation-in-c-c) might be a classmate who got a head start on this.

Comment: I tried to understand but it ain't easy at all... I read that pdf.

Comment: Yes, its a white paper. They are aimed to be precise and comprehensive, not easy.

Comment: This should be a comment in the question and a vote for closing, rather than an answer.